# Received Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle in Python

Tags: python, oserror

I am trying to invoke a Particular API .
Received the below Error

`OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`

I have set the HTTPS proxy also and set Environment variable to the below

```
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = os.path.join(
'/etc/ssl/certs/',
'ca-certificates.crt')
```

Please let me know how can i resolve the error .
Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have permissions to read /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt or does this file exist?

Comment: Yes it is default OS CA bundle

Comment: then this probably means that this CA bundle does not have the CA certificate for the CA that signed the certificate of the "Particular API"

Comment: I have checked it CA certificate is available for the website . 
can you let me know how can I check if CA certificate for the CA that signed the certificate of the "Particular API"